# alert() not working for document methods

Tags: javascript, html, alert

A really simple program, but I am not sure why its not getting executed.

Here's my HTML file :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
<title>Tag Name Locator</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
There are 3 different types of element in this body:
</p>
<ul>
<li>paragraph</li>
<li>unordered list</li>
<li>list item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And, here's the JavaScript:-

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++)
{
alert(listItems[i].nodeName);
}
```

But, no alert message is show.

Please help on this.

If I just use a single alert line like

```
alert("Welcome!")
```

Its properly shown when browser is loaded.

Any answers?

Comment: Kindly show your complete javascript code with script tags.

Comment: if that loop is inside _example.js_, wrap those into a method and call that method in `onload` of body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the javascript (if script included in header) fired before the DOM is fully loaded. So the listItems.length is 0 initially and hence the alert is not showing. So you need to put that javascript code in a function and call that function on onload event of the body tag. like this.

In HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
<title>Tag Name Locator</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body onload="PageLoaded()">
<p>
There are 3 different types of element in this body:
</p>
<ul>
<li>paragraph</li>
<li>unordered list</li>
<li>list item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

in JS

```
function PageLoaded()
{
   var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++)
    {
      alert(listItems[i].nodeName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your `js` before closing body.

```
    ...
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
    </body>
```

See what happens when you add in head http://jsfiddle.net/ManyE/

See what happens when you add in body http://jsfiddle.net/ManyE/1

Answer (score 1):

put JS file script at bottom

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>

<title>Tag Name Locator</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
There are 3 different types of element in this body:
</p>
<ul>
<li>paragraph</li>
<li>unordered list</li>
<li>list item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

alert not call due js file execute first while your DOM element are not ready. Better to user jQuery for same..

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is being called before [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) is completely built. Therefore, it is not aware those li elements exist. You need to call this javascript after the Document is loaded:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++)
    {
        alert(listItems[i].nodeName);
    }
}
```

or as many suggested, write it at the bottom of the page, which will ensure it executes after these are loaded into the DOM.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/KASLB/

Answer (score 1):

put your script at the end of the page

```
<body style="height:700px" >
    <p>
        There are 3 different types of element in this body:
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>paragraph</li>
        <li>unordered list</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. All the suggestions worked like a gem! Just started with DOM, so wasn't aware of this .